# How to push children array into the parent children array Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

After filtering the data, I am getting below response inside `findChildrens` function.

Now i am expecting is if `this.newRegion` have object length more than 1,
than it will merge children of second object inside the parent object children.

**For ex -** In below Response, i am getting two objects `"Africa" and "Europe"`, So i wanted to merge children of `"Europe"` inside the parent children of `"Africa".`

Can anyone please help me to push as my expected output.

```
findChildrens(){
     this.newRegion = [
      {
        "name": "Africa",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Test1",
            "region": "1UL Africa"
          },
          {
            "name": "Test2",
            "region": "South Africa",
          },
          {
            "name": "Test3",
            "region": "New Test",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Europe",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Test4",
            "region": "1UL Africa"
          },
          {
            "name": "Test5",
            "region": "Test Europe"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];    
  };
  
  };
```

**Expected Output**

```
this.newRegion = [
      {
        "name": "Africa",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Test1",
            "region": "1UL Africa"
          },
          {
            "name": "Test2",
            "region": "South Africa",
          },
          {
            "name": "Test3",
            "region": "New Test",
          },
           {
            "name": "Test4",
            "region": "1UL Africa"
          },
          {
            "name": "Test5",
            "region": "Test Europe"
          }
        ]
      }     
    ];    
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to do something like

```js
let newRegion = [
      {
        "name": "Africa",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Test1",
            "region": "1UL Africa"
          },
          {
            "name": "Test2",
            "region": "South Africa",
          },
          {
            "name": "Test3",
            "region": "New Test",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Europe",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Test4",
            "region": "1UL Africa"
          },
          {
            "name": "Test5",
            "region": "Test Europe"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];  
    
    let result=newRegion[0];
    if(newRegion.length>1){
    result.children=result.children.concat(newRegion.slice(1).map(obj=>obj.children).flat())
    }
    
    console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This function might be what you're looking. But I have to warn you that what you're trying to do is not scalable or representative of code best practices. You might want to edit this code a bit to make it works regardless of how many regions you have.

```js
// It might be preferable to store this in a constant
const REGIONS = [
  {
    "name": "Africa",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Test1",
        "region": "1UL Africa"
      },
      {
        "name": "Test2",
        "region": "South Africa",
      },
      {
        "name": "Test3",
        "region": "New Test",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Europe",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Test4",
        "region": "1UL Africa"
      },
      {
        "name": "Test5",
        "region": "Test Europe"
      }
    ]
  }
];

findChildren() {
  if (Object.keys(REGIONS).length > 1) {
    const mergedChildren = REGIONS[0].children.concat(REGIONS[1].children);
    return ({
      ...REGIONS[0],
      children: mergedChildren
    })
  } else {
    return REGIONS[0];
  }
}
```